# What is the purpose of @WebSocketServer() from nestJS/websocket?

Tags: websocket, nestjs

I'm studying webSocket management for a web server under nestJS framework.

When I read nestJS documentation (https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways), they only talks 3 lines about @WebSocketServer() :
"Occasionally, you may want to have a direct access to the native, platform-specific server instance. The reference to this object is passed as an argument to the afterInit() method (OnGatewayInit interface). Another option is to use the @WebSocketServer() decorator. "

```
@WebSocketServer()
server: Server;
```

Google didn't help me to give me more informations.
Source code commentary is :
"(alias) WebSocketServer(): PropertyDecorator
import WebSocketServer
Attaches native Web Socket Server to a given property."
And that's all !

For now i andertand that :

```
@WebSocketServer()
server: Server;
```

is equivalent to :

```
afterInit() {
server: new Server();
}
```

That can't be only that ? Or it is ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you will use the gateway @WebSocketGateway(80, { namespace: 'events' })
you only need to use the *@WebSocketServer* when you are outside of a websocket handler like so

```
@WebSocketServer()
private server: Server;

emitMessage(channel: string, message: string) {
  this.server.emit(channel, message);
}
```